# Change format of month in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm using this to make the dates in my bibliography appear as year month day, but the month is coming up as, e.g. "Mar." but I don't want the trailing dot.

```
  \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}\iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}%
\iffieldundef{#2}
  {}
  {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
   \iffieldundef{#3}{}{\space}}%
\iffieldundef{#3}
  {}
  {\thefield{#3}}%
}%
```

So it appears as e.g. (accessed 2015 Mar. 19) but I want (accessed 2015 Mar 19)

I can't find where the abbreviations are defined, I tried `dateabbrev=false` but then I get (accessed 2015 March 19).

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,british]{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{mwe.bib}
@report{example2015,
    author =    {John Doe},
    title =     {Example Website},
    url =       {http://www.example.com/},
    urldate =   {2015-03-19},
    year =      {2015}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,date=comp,urldate=comp]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{\bbl@main@language}
{
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
  %<year><month><day>
  \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}\iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\thefield{#3}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}
Hello.\autocite{example2015}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definitions for the abbreviations of the months are in `language.lbx` files, in your case in the `english.lbx` file. To modify the behaviour, you can use the local customisation command (see Section 3.8 of  the biblatex manual, `textbook biblatex`)

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    january   = Jan ,
    february  = Feb ,
    march     = Mar ,
    april     = Apr ,
    may       = May ,
    june      = Jun ,
    july      = Jul ,
    august    = Aug ,
    september = Sep,
    october   = Oct ,
    november  = Nov ,
    december  = Dec ,
}
```